# HTML Encoding alpha, beta, gamma

Tags: c#, .net, html, unicode

I am trying to HTML encode a string that contains alpha, beta, and gamma characters (α, β, γ
). Unfortunately, using the `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` is not encoding these characters. Is there some other function in the .NET library that would encode these to HTML?

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to encode them? αβγ and most other Unicode characters can be included directly, unencoded in an HTML document, as long as the encoding it's written in matches the `<meta>` charset. It's generally better to try to fix charset issues rather than work around it with HTML-encoding, when possible. (This is why `HtmlEncode` leaves all but HTML-special characters alone.)

Comment: @bobince, Under normal circumstances I wouldn't be concerned with encoding them. I am encoding them because we have a third party application that has problems reading those characters from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any built in tool for this, but you can use this handy function:

```
public string ForceHtmlEncode(string input)
{
    return string.Concat(input.Select(c => "&#" + (int)c + ";"));
}
```

This will simply convert all characters in the string to HTML entities.

Comment: Thanks. That would get the job done. I ended up using a function found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20255/Full-HTML-Character-Encoding-in-C

Comment: @Justin nice, must say I never saw this before posting my own code. Same result, except the code you found won't encode "ordinary" characters.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this for the html visual 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp